# UWP, MVVM and cascade ListView

Tags: listview, mvvm, uwp, observablecollection

I'm becoming crazy with UWP and two ListView. The scenario is simple: I have in a page two listview (*listview* and *listViewField*).

I have a ViewModel like:

```
public class FormViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<TableInfo> Tables;
}
```

*TableInfo* has the following definition:

```
public class TableInfo {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the fields.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The fields.</value>
    public List<FieldInfo> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

At the end I want to have something like:

[image: ListView UWP]

*listview* shows all *Name* from Tables (point n. 1). When a user click on an item in *listview*, *listviewField* shows the list of field for this item (point n. 2). If I want to change or add a new field, the user can use the form (point n. 3).

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind vm.Tables, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="mdl:TableInfo">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="25" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView x:Name="listViewTable" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem.Fields}"
          SelectedIndex="{x:Bind vm.SelectedTableInfoIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="mdl:FieldInfo">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="25" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If I insert in *Tables* at the beginning some items, I can see the list in the first listview and (magically) if I click on an item, I can see all fields in the second listview. But I try to add a field from the form, nothing is working fine.

Do you have any suggestions or a good example for that? Thank you in advance.

#### Update

With the help of @ibebbs, I changed the *listview* and below you can find my `BaseViewModel`. I tried in different way to add some `TableInfo` and `FieldInfo` across the *viewmodel* but the first listview doesn't show anything.
If I added some `TableInfo` when the application starts immediately after the initialization of the *viewmodel*, the listviews are working as I expect.

I added a function to add a new `TableInfo`

```
public void AddTableInfo(TableInfo tbl) {
    Tables.Add(tbl);
    RaisePropertyChanged("Tables");
}
```

#### Second update

As @MZetko suggested, I added in the binding `x:Bind vm.Tables, Mode=OneWay` and the listview is updated when I add new items.

The last problem is how to connect a selected item with a form (point n. 3).

```
public int SelectedTableInfoIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTableInfoIndex; }
    set {
        _selectedTableInfoIndex = value;
        if (_selectedTableInfoIndex >= 0) {
            _selectedTableInfo = Tables[_selectedTableInfoIndex];
        }
    }
}
private int _selectedTableInfoIndex = -1;

public TableInfo SelectedTableInfo
{
    get {
        return (_selectedTableInfoIndex >= 0) ? Tables[_selectedTableInfoIndex] : null;
    }
    set {
        _selectedTableInfo = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTableInfo");
    }
}
private TableInfo _selectedTableInfo;
```

Then I should have in my form data from my model listview.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackTable" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10">
    <TextBlock>Table name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="textboxTableName" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
    <TextBlock>Project namespace</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="textboxNameSpace" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem.ProjectNameSpace}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This piece of code shows the item in the form, one for table and another for field. Now my question is: what do I change if I want to add a new record or delete one?

I'm looking around and I found those link

- https://github.com/johnshew/Minimal-UWP-MVVM-CRUD/tree/master/Simple%20MVVM%20UWP%20with%20CRUD
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/

but I don't have a clear idea how to use it in my case.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you've defined the ObservableCollection<TableInfo> Tables as a public __field__ not a public __property__. Binding and change notification only works with properties which is why you're not seeing any changes when this method is called.

Comment: Also, if an answer / comment proves helpful, you should mark it as the correct answer and/or up-vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second ListView is binding to the Fields property of TableInfo which is of type `List<FieldInfo>`. A List doesn't support change notification which the databinding relies on in order to update the UI.

Change the `List<FieldInfo>` to `ObservableCollection<FieldInfo>` and you should see better results.

Incidentally, I'd suggest only binding the ItemsSource in the second ListView rather than binding the DataContext and ItemsSource (which requires two refreshes of the UI). It should be as simply as:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind vm.Tables}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="mdl:TableInfo">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="25" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView x:Name="listViewTable" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem.Fields}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="mdl:FieldInfo">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="25" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I remove the *DataContext* when I click on an item, the second listview doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you include the change I made to the ItemsSource binding string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the problem is that the second list view does not update when new fields are added.

The problem lies in the fact, that the list of fields is of type `List<FieldInfo>`. Databinding in UWP is based on the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces. `List` does not implement either and can't hence automatically inform the user interface that it has changed. To do this, you will need to replace it with `ObservableCollection<FieldInfo>`. When you add an item to this collection, the UI will automatically be updated with the new item.

Unfortunately however, that will still not be enough to be able to update a field. The `ObservableCollection` class can observe changes like `Add` or `Remove` of items, but can't observe changes of individual items inside of it.
To be able to do that, you will have to make sure `FieldInfo` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that the `PropertyChanged` event is called whenever a property you want to observe changes.

The most common implementation of the interface looks like this:

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Now in all the properties you need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` method:

```cs
private string _description = "";

public string Description
{
    get
    {
        return _description;
    }
    set
    {
        _description = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Because of the `[CallerMemberAttribute]` you don't have to specify the `propertyName` argument, and it will be automatically filled out by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've implemented such a similar things but it doesn't work. For example if I try to read some data from file and add each table `TableInfo` to the `ObservableCollection<TableInfo>`, I can't see anything on the *listview* (the first one).

Comment: Please, update the question with the changes so that I can see it :-)

Comment: x:Bind syntax is by default one time only. You should change the bind to `{x:Bind Tables, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: you're right. Now when I load something from file is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I publish my `BaseViewModel` if someone needs one

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    #region Property changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName, Action<bool> message) {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
            // property changed
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            message?.Invoke(this.IsValid);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">The property.</param>
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    // SetField(()=> somewhere.Name = value; somewhere.Name, value) 
    // Advanced case where you rely on another property
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(T currentValue, T newValue, Action DoSet, 
                                  [CallerMemberName] String property = null) {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(currentValue, newValue)) return false;
        DoSet.Invoke();
        RaisePropertyChanged(property);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```